Do LEGO video game questions belong here or on Gaming?
There's a handful of questions about LEGO video games on Gaming SE right now. If I have a question about a video game, do I continue asking there since video games are quite different from the physical building sets themselves, or will they be on topic here as well?

Yes, I think they should be asked on the Gamming SE as this one is about building stuff, not playing a video game. I enjoy the LEGO video-games but I think they are totally different things.
